One single appversion for helm charts replicated into several charts
Currently my app has 11 modules and this implies that I have a file chart for each module.
I would like to centralise this version to avoid changing it in each file every time I want to deploy.
My charts look like this:
apiVersion: v2
appversion: 1.4.0-CTLQ-SNAPSHOT
description: Helm chart to deploy service1
name: service1
version: 1.4.0-CTLQ-SNAPSHOT

apiVersion: v2
appversion: 1.4.0-CTLQ-SNAPSHOT
description: Helm chart to deploy service2
name: service2
version: 1.4.0-CTLQ-SNAPSHOT

... 11 times
So I would like to have the version 1.4.0-CTLQ-SNAPSHOT defined somewhere as a variable, and be able to reference it directly from each chart.

You can try adding version from the version flag like helm install   --version  1.4.0-CTLQ-SNAPSHOT
